# How to remove metadata google_play_services_version?

Tags: google-play-services, bundle, manifest

I was coding, and appears to add one library, I pressed add and

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.1.0'
```

was added, but I DONT NEED IT (now)

then in manifest was added

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

but as I DONT need it, i delete both, 
Now if I try compile

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

is automatically added again 
and this error shows

Error:(66, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').

I repeat I DONT want to add it now. 
and I have delete it in bundle

Comment: I found a solution, i copied the manifest content, I delete the file, and i create it again, and paste the content, and delete the content-part  of google play services, and this was not auto added again.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio, open AndroidManifest.xml in other text editor remove those lines and save.

```
<!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for App Indexing. See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

And then rebuild project again.